# jQuery First Upper With Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a function that returns upper of first letter of each word in my string:

```
function firstUpper( str )
{
    return str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
}

firstUpper( "MY TEST" );
//returns "My Test"
```

Ok. But I need to change my regex because it does not work like this:

```
firstUpper( "MY-TEST" );
//returns "My-test"
```

I want my function returns this: `"My-Test"`

Comment: I believe you just need `/\b./gi` or `/\b[a-z]/gi` - see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/81xehpbb/) (Note that `\b` will not work with Unicode letters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to amend your RegEx to work when there is a `-` prefix before the character:

```
/^(.)|\s(.)|-(.)/g
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/hrexpk6v/)

Comment: Alteration is of little use here. As there might be other characters too.

Comment: @noob I'm not sure of your point. If the previous expression suited the OPs requirement, then this will too.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan it works! u forgot `/g` at your post.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I left out the `/g` as the flags didn't need changing, only the expression itself. I added it in just to save any confusion.

Comment: For strings like this `HELLO MR O'BRAIN.` result is `Hello Mr O'brain.`. In such cases alteration is of little use.

Comment: so what regex do you suggest to use @noob ?

Comment: @Thiago: It depends on your requirement. Which characters you would want to match against. But am sure if you do that by using alteration it will be a long regex. For now this solution will work for you.

Comment: @Thiago: You could use `/^.|[\s-]./g` and expand the character class to include more characters if need be. Since you are not using the captured substrings, I see no need in `(...)`